# php:Mysql: Question bank database design

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns

i have a problem in my database designing for a php project of QUestion bank in which

user can create a questions and assign to it unlimited number of answers.

the problem is i currently store the questions as follows :

> ID, Question , Answer
>   1  , "hood color?"    , "green=hgreen,yellow=yellow"

i store all Answers with , as a seperatore and an = to separate the real value from the value that should be shown to user !.

so above example would be

```
<span>Hood color</span>
<input type=checkbox value=hyellow>yellow
<input type=checkbox value=hgreen>green
```

any better ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a different table for the answers:

> ```
> Table Questions:
> QuestionId
> Question
>
> Table Answers:
> AnswerId
> QuestionId
> Answer (real answer)
> Caption (caption to be shown to the user)
> ```

edit:

Selecting questions and their answers. Returns nothing for questions without answers.

```
select
  q.QuestionId,
  q.Question,
  a.AnswerId,
  a.Answer,
  a.Caption
from
  Questions q
  inner join Answers a on a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
```

Change `inner join` to `left join` to get a single row for questions without answers. a.* will be NULL in those rows.

Other solution, query a list of questions first and get the answer for each question:

```
select
  a.AnswerId,
  a.Answer,
  a.Caption
from
  Answers a
where 
  a.QuestionId = <QuestionId you retrieved before>
```

Comment: Nearly right - nothing here to indicate which is the correct answer - to normalise properly, the correct answer should be referenced as FK in the question table - but this is probably overkill, and a simpler solution would be to store it in the answer table.

Comment: nice solution, only problem will be with multi select questions.
as some quesitons will have more than an answer, and each answer will have  a real and a caption. so how this can be done ? thats my problem

Answer (score 0):

PHP has some pretty good JSON support, you could save it as a JSON string `({"green": "hgreen", "yellow": "hyellow"})`

Answer (score 0):

table users, and a table answers (with 2 or more columns like "right_answer" and "wrong_answer" ...) maybe you can use mysql workbench for creating the databse structure =)